# Android best way to send and receive from/to a server

Tags: java, android, sockets, communication

I am developing an App which need to communicate with server every minute, and let the server know the position of the client. The server is in java.

I did it in UDP but with this I have to do a lot of checks, for example if I send my "profile description" the server has to send me a packet with "Ok, I received your new profile description".

I have to send pictures, and with UDP I need to send a lot of packets and server has to send me the confirmation of received, also I have to tell him that the last packet I sent was the last and so it can set my picture as profile picture.

I think UDP could be useless, I need to send informations as fast I can to give to the server my position but I also need that informations like Name/Description/Picture are received correctly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sort of question is too broad and partially opinion based. Stackoverflow is for mostly programming based questions.

Comment: @Chackle Where should I ask?

Comment: I would personally use TCP for what you're asking, but you should be more focused on what library you should use to help your situation. For this, I would look into Volley library by Google. It's pretty neat for GET and POST requests, which from what you're saying is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP differs from TCP in that you DON'T expect an acknowledged confirmation response.
For example, UDP will be best for video conference, because if 25 picture frames are sent to the server every second, and 4-5 are lost on the way - there is no reason to send the lost frames again, and therefore no reason to get an acknowledged confirmation response for each frame.
However, UDP will not be the best for sending a profile picture, because if the server didn't received the picture - it has to be sent over and over again, until we get an acknowledged confirmation response from the server, saying it got the picture.

You wrote:

> an App which need to communicate with server every minute, and let the server know the position of the client

UDP might be a good practice here, because maybe you don't really care if a few network packages are lost (because others will be sent later on).

However, you also wrote:

> for example if I send my "profile description" the server has to send me a packet with "Ok, I received your new profile description".

and

> I have to send pictures, and with UDP I need to send a lot of packets and server has to send me the confirmation of received

for this 2 jobs, I'll recommend using TCP - because you need to make sure that lost packages are sent again. Even better, you can study some more about REST APIs to see if it suits you.
A link for a tutorial of uploading a picture in a REST API (one of many on Google): http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/jersey-file-upload-example/

For conclusion I recommend you divide the 3 jobs into 2 groups: UDP (the location every minute) and TCP/REST API (profile description and photo upload). If you want to choose only one then go for the TCP/REST API.

Hope it helps!